# Internet Explorer 8 unresponsive scroll bar

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, scrollbar

The page with the problem is on [*link no longer works*] and can only be reproduced in IE8 (XP Pro).

I have two scrollbars on the page, one for a nav menu and one for the main page. The scrolling area on the left can be controlled using a mouse wheel, but the scroll bar controls do not function (the up/down arrows, clicking and dragging the arrow). The right scrollbar works as expected. (btw, you can add more content the the nav by clicking 'Lineup' to make it scroll at a taller height)

There doesn't appear to be anyone else, that I can find, that has come across this behavior, and I'm not really sure how to debug it. I've tried recreating multiple scrolling panes, with/without absolute positioning, various z-indexes, and resizing the elements. Anybody have any ideas?